# how to get id of input box?

Tags: javascript

when my webpage load then on console array of id showing

[image: web page]

But when the whole page load array of id disappear

[enter code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcUP1.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcUP1.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsdWq.png

And my main problem in this image

[enter image description here][2][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ci3I.png

that is my code

so how to save id in var $write = $(":input").on('focus').map((i, el) => el.id).get();

and when its save in the $write function so where the cursor the value go in it.

But in it typing in one input box gets text on all input box. I want typing in one and value get in one whyen cursor update

like when my mouse cursor in itemNo_1 so the value go in that input box and when itemNo_2 so the value go in that input box. 
please help me.

```
$(function(){
        var $write = $(":input").on('focus').map((i, el) => el.id).get();   
        shift = false,
        capslock = false;
        backspace  = false;
        console.log(Object.values($write));
            $('#keyboard li').click(function(){
                var $this = $(this),
                    character = $this.html(); 

                // Shift keys
                if ($this.hasClass('left-shift') || $this.hasClass('right-shift')) {
                    $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
                    $('.symbol span').toggle();

                    shift = (shift === true) ? false : true;
                    capslock = false;
                    backspace  = false;
                    return false;
                }

                // Caps lock
                if ($this.hasClass('capslock')) {
                    $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
                    capslock = true;
                    return false;
                }

                // backspace lock
                if ($this.hasClass('backspace')) {
                    $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
                    capslock = true;
                    return false;
                }

                // Delete
                    if ($this.hasClass('delete')) {
                        var html = $write.html(),
                        txt = html.substr(0, html.length - 1);
                      $write.html(txt);
                      $write.autocomplete("search", txt);
                      return false;
                    }
                    // Delete

                // Special characters
                if ($this.hasClass('symbol')) character = $('span:visible', $this).html();
                if ($this.hasClass('space')) character = ' ';
                if ($this.hasClass('tab')) character = "\t";
                if ($this.hasClass('return')) character = "\n";

                // Uppercase letter
                if ($this.hasClass('uppercase')) character = character.toUpperCase();

                // Remove shift once a key is clicked.
                if (shift === true) {
                    $('.symbol span').toggle();
                    if (capslock === false) $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');

                    shift = false;
                }
                //console.log("DO IT ", character);
                // Add the character
                $write.val($write.val() + character);       
                $write.html(txt);
                $write.autocomplete("search", txt);


            }); 
        });
```

rest code is

here

```
 $(function () {
     var write = write();       
     write.init("keyboard");
     //first input focus
     var $firstInput = $(":input").first().focus();
     write.currentElement = $firstInput;
     write.currentElementCursorPosition = 0;
 });
```

Comment: how I solve this please give some suggestion.

Comment: you are using map in wrong way, map((i, el) should be map((el,i)